# Swift 3 / Alamofire 4 how to send Data/NSData [Uint8] in request?

Tags: swift, alamofire, nsdata

I have 16 bytes [UInt8] which I need to send to a Node.js backend for storage in a MySQL column binary(16). However, I can only seem to send String values within the parameters dictionary of a request in Alamofire 4, I am unable to send other data types.

I have tried encoding the [Uint8] into utf8 and then sending it as a String within the parameters dictionary, but some of values are not valid utf8 characters so this fails often. Any Ideas? Thanks.

Comment: Do you control the server code? Then (as I suggested in a previous thread) send the data hex-encoded, and decode it on the server side, before inserting the the data in the database. – If you don't control the server code then you'll have to find out what format it expects.

Comment: I do control the server code, I also have the option of creating the UUID's on the server side was just worried during a peak in traffic generating UUID's / converting Hex back to Bytes would use crucial server processing time so have been attempting to generate client side. Thanks for your input, I will probably go with converting from String of Hex to bytes in Javascript.